# Why might the chirality of gastopods be dominantly dextral?

Tags: genetics, evolution, natural-selection, molluscs, symmetry

This wikipedia page on [gastropods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastropod_shell#Chirality) provides a definition of chirality, and briefly describes the genetic mechanisms behind why a shell is wound left (sinistral) or right (dextral) handed. It also mentions the fact that there are more species of gastropods that are dextrally wound than sinistral. What the page does not offer is why this might be so with regards to evolutionary pressures.

Does anyone have an explanation of why gastopod species have wound up dominantly dextral?

This [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44209/does-the-species-of-snake-that-eats-amphidromous-inversus-have-chiral-dimorphism) relates to my question about a *specific* species of gastopod that is found in equal proportion of both chiralities, and both in the question and answer there are suggestions of a chiral relationship between predator and prey and perhaps ease of mating. But it really doesn't answer my general question.

If it's a predator-prey pressure then is there any evidence across a larger sample of species that supports this explanation? Or of the left and right handed species of gastropods, anatomical evidence across a large number of species that shows mating advantages? Or likewise any other explanations that offer evidence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the species of snake that eats Amphidromous inversus have chiral dimorphism?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44209/does-the-species-of-snake-that-eats-amphidromous-inversus-have-chiral-dimorphism)

Comment: I don't think the question _per se_ is a duplicate, but @Remi.b's answer covers this nicely.